# Why is it important to prove that some particular set is a vector space as opposed to just asserting such objects exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, soft-question, philosophy

In Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right Example 1.24, we are asked to prove that the set of all functions from some set S to the set of real (or complex) numbers is a vector space.

I proved this by using the definitions of the vector sum and scalar product associated with this set of functions and by using the fact that the output of these function are elements in the set of real or complex numbers, and thus as elements in fields, the properties of fields such as the distributivity of multiplication over addition and the existence of an additive inverse apply.

My problem is that to me, this seems like a lot of reasoning just to say that the real-valued ouput of a function behaves in the way that we all know real numbers do, just from our rather fundamental human experience of the world as $\mathbb R^3$. It even seems a little tautological ("opium causes sleep by virtue of its dormitive power") = ("a vector space onto a field is a vector space by virtue of a field being such a thing that makes a vector space when you add the right operations to it"). Why is the naive, "intuitive", or "geometrical" understanding we can from experience insufficient and this style of proof illuminating? What does humanity gain from being able to give a demonstration like this as opposed to just asserting when convenient that such a thing as a vector space exists when we need to use it to perform a certain type of calculation?

I fully admit that I am probably so ignorant of the matter that I can't even begin to see how, but how can I come to see that if that is so?

Comment: “From our rather fundamental human experiences of the world as $\Bbb R^3$” So how do you know your human experiences exactly corresponds to every mathematical fact of $\Bbb R^3$? Furthermore,  when I look around, I don’t see the air around me, or the objects in my home, or the road I walk labeled with coordinates such as $(1.09786,-5.8756,0.09897)$.

Comment: I don't need to, I only need to know that $\mathbb R^3$ is a useful idea insofar as it corresponds to phenomena I can observe (presumably I can deduce the relevant properties that characterize a field by demonstrating their use in measuring physical, extensive objects).

Comment: But what is $\Bbb R^3$? You have to be able to formulate that before you can use it describe the world. And because you are trying to use it to describe the world, presumably it shouldn’t on any aspects of the physical world. Besides, if you characterize $\Bbb R^3$ by measuring physical objects, considering the limits measurements, you can only get so precise. So you should only need rational numbers which only get to a certain number of digits after the decimal point, perhaps with the addition of the results of certain operations (like logarithms, radicals).

Comment: And so in a sense, you don’t need the majority of what most people call $\Bbb R^3$. You’re working in a different thing, you just call it $\Bbb R^3$ also. And maybe another person might find certain numbers you use redundant for measurements purposes, or someone might find a quantity lacking a good number to represent it in your idea. This gives rise to a problem: Whose $\Bbb R^3$ is supposed to be the true, the objective, the indisputable $\Bbb R^3$? How do we even start to choose any candidates, let alone decide on one?

Comment: I'm fine admitting the notion of the reals is totally parasitic on rational numbers. Something to do with Aristotle's resolution of Zeno's paradox. It seems that is usually we encounter them anyway by measuring things, and then observing a quantity that exceeds or is deficient from the measure we have chosen to some degree, that may be arbitrarily refined, but it is unclear if in all situations arbitrary precision is even useful or meaningful.

Comment: I assert that the set of maps from the real numbers to the circle of unit norm numbers in $\mathbb C$ is a vector space.

Comment: Occasionally, mathematicians prove very unintuitive properties of mathematical objects based on how certain chosen axioms interact with one another. If you are dealing with a mathematical object and are able to prove that its properties fulfill a certain set of axioms then you get all of the very clever proofs related to those axioms for free. However, There are times when you may intuitively believe something is clearly a vector space but when you sit down to actually prove it, you're wrong. Which can be very illuminating as to why a certain approach toward a problem had failed to work.

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is that to me, this seems like a lot of reasoning just to say that the real-valued ouput of a function behaves in the way that we all know real numbers do, just from our rather fundamental human experience of the world as R3

We do not experience the world around us as the set $\mathbb R^3$. There are no coordinates floating around us. Moreover there is no obvious way to agreeing upon where $(0,0,0)$ is. Our world is clearly coordinate free.

Not only do we not experience the world around us as the set $\mathbb R^3$ but even less so as a vector space $\mathbb R^3$. Is it clear when looking around us that we have a operations $+$ and a multiplication giving a vector space structure ? I don't think so.

---

Additionally it is not because something seems "intuitive" or "obvious" that it is actually mathematically easy to prove. In fact it happens quite often that something which seems intuitive is actually just false.

An example of this is when dealing with infinite sums

$$ \Sigma = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ...$$

You might believe that switching the order in which you sum the terms $a_i$ will not affect the value of $\Sigma$, but that is not the case.